# Certificate for WPF Browser App

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0, xbap

i am developing a full trust wpf browser application . 
Am i have to make .pfx file after every debug or run ? ( to install on client machine )
 or only one .pfx file works after every build and works on every client machine ??